# BLE enable Notify failed

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want open premession of notify in my application
but it's always return false

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Please, post the CODE, not an IMAGE. Show the BLE connection, reading & writing. If you are trying to read a value with that code, you won't get it, BLE doesn't work like that. If that is what you want, I can provide some examples.

Comment: Sorry,i'm new to Android.

Comment: i'm want to get the message from BLE device,so i need to enable notify in my application when message back to my application i can get it form the onCharacteristicChange() method

Comment: You didn't post your code.

Comment: Please find the solution     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903419/unable-to-read-write-some-characateristics-from-ble-device-using-the-bluetoothle/40904252#40904252

Comment: Are you possibly writing multiple descriptors before waiting for the onDescriptorWrite result callback before writing the next one?